# Load files from Appdata in seed method entity framework

Tags: c#, visual-studio

So I've just upgraded my computer to win10, re-installed VS 2015 and copied my project file across.
Now when I try and run update-database I get the error below.

The code is working on my other workstation. Does anyone know what the correct way of accessing the App_Data folder within a project is?

In my seed method:

```
        var firstFilePath = @"MyApp\App_Data\CS201510071501.pdf";
        var firstFileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(firstFilePath );

        var secondFilePath= @"MyApp\App_Data\689810.pdf";
        var secondFileBytes= System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(secondFilePath);
```

After running update-database

> Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\BeatBoxV2\App_Data\CS201510071501.pdf'

Comment: If it was helpful, please dont forget to up vote X)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to get the path:

```
var appDataPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("DataDirectory").ToString();
var firstFilePath = Path.Combine(appDataPath,"App_Data","CS201510071501.pdf");
var secondFilePath = Path.Combine(appDataPath,"App_Data","689810.pdf");
```